# WebAPI Default URL

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am looking at using WebAPI to create a Restful API. I want to create a launch url to provide URLs to the other portions/entities of the API. The obvious place to do this is ~/api/ however I cannot seem to wire up a route that will not give a 403 result. Any ideas?

EDIT: Just to be a bit clearer. I know how the default routing works in WebAPI, I.E. if I create a CustomersController that inherits from ApiController I can get there using ~/api/customers. What I want is a step before that where I could go to ~/api/ and would get a result a bit like:

```
[
   { Title: 'Customers', Url: '~/api/customers' }
]
```

I want this as my understanding is that RESTful services are metadata (think that the term) driven (basically discoverable and provide links to other resources in result). So there should be a single source url that points to all other resources in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do for this is to add a new route which handles `~/api` specifically.

In your project you will notice in the `Application_Start` method in the `Global.asax` a call is made to `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)`, the `WebApiConfig` class is included in your project in the `App_Start` folder (along with various other config classes). If you look at the implementation of the `Register` call you will see that's where the `~/api/controller` route is actually setup i.e.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In order to make `~/api` discoverable all you need to do is introduce a new route *before* the default which handles any calls to `~/api` e.g.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DiscoverableApi",
    routeTemplate: "api",
    defaults: new { controller = "Discoverable", }
);
```

Then add an `ApiController` to handle that call e.g.

```
public class DiscoverableController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "/users", "/photos", "/history" };
    }
}
```

If you don't want to hard-code your URLs you will most likely need to look at something like Reflection to enumerable all the available `ApiController`'s and their reachable endpoints (i.e. actions).

Comment: Hi James, I understand that but I want a starting URL to point consumers at ~/api/users. RESTful should be discoverable (think the preferred term is metadata driven but I forget for sure). To this end I think there should be a single starting URL as the server should be controlling all other urls.

Comment: @SimonBull Sorry I may have misinterpreted your question then! So you mean you want consumers to query `~/api` and return a list of all available calls? i.e. `/users, /photos, /history` etc.

Comment: Bang on. I have just updated my question to hopefully make it a bit clearer what I was meaning.

Comment: You edited answer was what I tried first. However the reason it does not work for me (an anyone who uses the default WebAPI templete) is that I put my ApiControllers in a folder called Api. If I change the route prefix to service/... then all is well. So assuming you do not use Api as the folder name for your ApiControllers this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Help Page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/4.0.0) package from NuGet. Out of the box you can create a list of all your API endpoints which are returned as an MVC View. However you could customise it to return Json instead. You can also configure it to hang off any route you want, i.e.

```
api.mysite.com/help
myapi.com/api
etc
```